# Visual Studio 2013: Cannot start "acquire developer license" flow. Brings up control panel instead

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm trying to update a Windows 8 app using Visual Studio 2013 (on Windows 10), but I can't seem to acquire a developer license. When I click "Project -> Store -> Acquire developer license" it just opens up the control panel on the "For developers" section where Developer mode is already enabled. (The same thing happens when I run Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration in PowerShell.). Without the license I'm not able to create store packages. Hopefully someone has an idea.

Comment: why do you ask the same [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49205564/1466046)?

Comment: I think my internet died on me before it posted. Then I posted it again on the same page and it must've posted it twice. Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: You did not need a license to create a package, it was needed to *run* it.  Pretty miserable busy-work, retired when Win10 allowed flipping the OS into developer mode.  So everything sounds normal, you just forgot to take the next step.

Comment: @HansPassant: The problem is that the "Create package" option is grayed out in the Project -> Store menu (as well as "Associate app with store"). I figured that it was grayed out because no license was yet acquired. But now you're telling me that's not necessary. Any idea why I can't create any packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to increase the version number in the manifest and clean/rebuild the project.